# How to hide individual XPages from being accessed from a webbrowser

Tags: browser, hide, xpages

I have a database with many xpages, sometimes the xpage is not ready for production and sometimes I just want to keep some xpages within the database without users allowed to access them.

In Domino Designer xpages view there are columns for show and hide design from notes and web but there are no place to change these column values.

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to hide an xpage from being accessed from a webbrowser without making changes to the xpage itself. i.e changing the Notes/Web values or giving them a special name?

Note: I am looking for a way to do this without adding or changing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to hide sadly (Create a PMR for an enhancement request).

You could try signing the XPages with a signature that doesn't have the right to run on the production server. That way the users would not be able to render the pages.

Comment: This answer was based on the limitation of: "I want to know if there is a way to hide an xpage from being accessed from a webbrowser without making changes to the xpage itself."

Comment: Yes, you answered my question

Answer (score 6):

You could use the ACL of the XPage by setting it to a role that a normal user won't have:

```
<xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
            <xp:this.entries>
                <xp:aclEntry right="NOACCESS" fullName="Anonymous"
                    loaded="true" name="Anonymous" type="ANONYMOUS">
                </xp:aclEntry>
        </xp:this.entries></xp:acl>
</xp:this.acl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not aware of any way of achieving this on specific pages without actually modifying those pages, I recommend using the page ACL feature:

1. Create a role entry with `EDITOR` access
2. Create a default entry with `NOACCESS`

So the XML source would look similar to the following:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
            <xp:this.entries>
                <xp:aclEntry right="EDITOR" type="ROLE">
                    <xp:this.name><![CDATA[[Developer]]]></xp:this.name>
                </xp:aclEntry>
                <xp:aclEntry right="NOACCESS" type="DEFAULT" />
            </xp:this.entries>
        </xp:acl>
    </xp:this.acl>
```

When the page is ready to be accessed by end users, you can either change the access level for the default entry or simply delete the page ACL entirely. In the meantime, only those with the `[Developer]` role can access the page.

**Disclaimer:** by far a more elegant approach is to use version control. I highly recommend watching [NotesIn9 episode 131](http://notesin9.com/index.php/2013/11/12/notesin9-131-use-sourcetree-for-better-xpages-source-control/) to learn how to use processes like GitFlow / HgFlow to easily manage "feature branches". This allows you to begin development of experimental or long-term changes, and occasionally make progress on them, but switch back to "master" whenever you want to push polished changes to the users without either infecting production with unpolished code or losing your in-progress features.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably I don't really get the issue: other than with the Notes Client we don't have a menu from which a user could select a "restricted" page. If it can be accessed from some kind of navigator then probably you should start by removing any links.

Apart from that: if after all users manage to access a restricted page they most probably would receive some kind of ugly standard http error code which usually we should try to avoid in the first place.

So, instead of restricting or hiding the page one easy solution could be an unconditional (or conditional) *redirection*  using

```
context.redirectToPage("/someUnrestrictedPage.xsp")
```

I'm using this in an application with an anonymous start page. There's no use showing  that page to authenticated users as it most likely would confuse them. So if non-anonymous users manage to access it e.g. through a browser bookmark they are immediately redirected to some other page. I put the code into the startpage's afterPageLoad.